# Magento How many times event is triggered

Tags: php, magento

Is there any way to know how many times event is being triggered and from where in whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **app/Mage.php** search for method **dispatchEvent**

Put a log on events.

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
    {
        Mage::log($name, null, 'eventLog.log', true); // log event name
        Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        return $result;
    }
```

Check eventLog.log file. There you can find how many times an event has occurred.

Comment: Thank you Ankita! that is what I was waiting for ;) but can it also tells from which module event is being triggered? It will be more helpful for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can not predict it.

Because observer is called whenever its related event is fired in Magento.

And such event for observer is dispatched from many Magento files.

Comment: What actually happened is I was getting duplicate emails it took me hours to find out the issue same observer was triggered from other module for sending email. So, I was wondering if there is any shortcut to find out how many times same observer is called.

Comment: Ok. So you can try after disabling other module if possible.

Comment: Yes I have solved the issue but it was very time taking I was just curios to know If there is any other way in magento to find out

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php search for method dispatchEvent() method. Put a log on $eventName and $observers. You will get the observes for the events.